# Fix the plot margins when plotting multiple plots in one

Tags: r

Attached herewith is the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Ave.png) that I got by the provided code. (partial code is given). To avoid this issue with plot margins, how should I proceed?

```
plot(density(SouthAmerica5), col=5, 
      main = "Height Distribution of South America") 
 lines(density(SouthAmerica4), col=4) 
 lines(density(SouthAmerica3), col=3) 
 lines(density(SouthAmerica2), col=2)
 lines(density(SouthAmerica1), col=1)
```

Comment: You can adjust the limits by adding the `xlim=c(100, 200), ylim=c(0, 0.5)` options to the `plot` function.  Adjust the lower and upper limits accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. Though this is a minor adjustment, this is the exact answer I expected. Cheers!  :)

Comment: Small edit for someone else who would find this answer (comment) helpful: `ylim=c(0, 0.05)`